# How to remove "account" from aud claim in KeyCloak?

Tags: keycloak

I created in the latest Keycloak version using the Admin UI a new client and a user and Evaluate the Client Scopes directly. In the generated access token we can see:

```
"iss": "..."
"aud": "account"
"sub": "..."
```

We can change the "aud" by adding a new mapper via "-dedicated" but we can't remove the "account" item. Why is this added and can we remove it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The claim `aud` refers to the *audience* of the current token. In other words, `aud` represents the services that should accept the given token.

> Why is this added ...?

In Keycloak, by default, the claim `aud` already contains a reference to the client `account`. This happens because by default:

1. a newly created client comes with an unfiltered scope (*i.e.,* has scope on all roles)
2. users are assigned with client roles from the `account` client, which provides access to the account console of Keycloak.

> ... can we remove it?

Yes, regarding point 1, if you go to your new client, switch to the tab `Client Scopes`, click on the scope `<client-id>-dedicated`, and then switch to the tab `Scope` you will see the following:

[image]

There you can switch off the `Full scope allowed` option, and then manually add the roles that should show up on the token (by using the `Assign role` menu). By not including any of the roles related to the client `account`, you are (indirectly) excluding any reference of that client on the `aud` claim. Bear in mind, however, that changes to this client will affect all the users using it to authenticate.

The other option is regarding point 2, if you go to users, click on your user, then switch to the tab `Role Mapping` and unselect the option `Hide inherited roles`, you will see the following:

[image]

As you can see to the newly created users, Keycloak assigns, among  others, the client roles `manage-account-links`, `manage-account`, and `view-profile`. Those roles are client roles from the `account` client. You could unassign them from the user, which would indirectly exclude any reference of the `account` client from the `aud` claim on tokens omitted by any client to that user. This is inadvisable, since normally one wants their users to access the Keycloak account console.

IMO, the first option is the one to go if you really want to exclude the `account` from the audience.